# How to create an auxiliary power supply

Tags: power-supply, robotics

For our senior design we are designing an electric vehicle. The motor will run on 72v from li ion batteries but we have some auxiliary devices that we would like to power from the same battery. We have some LEDs that require 12v DC and probably max of 2amps. How does one basically take a branch of the main power and scale it for auxiliary uses?

My initial idea is to use a DC DC converter in parallel with the power supply coming from the batteries. The converter would essentially be a 72v max input and then be a 12v 2Amp output. Is this a good strategy?

Also I'm new to stack exchange so all help is appreciated.

---

Thanks for all your help. We are definitely looking at a buy option rather than make given we are a group of just mechanical engineers with limited electrical engineering experience. So I was looking on digikey and I found a 25w 12v output DC DC converter from 72v input. (Digikey part number: [SD-25C-12-ND](http://www.bb-elec.com/Products/Datasheets/sd-25-spec.pdf)). Does that seem like it would be the right fit for our application?

Comment: If the main battery becomes depleted, would it be desirable to still be able to, say, flash the hazard warning indicators? If so, then perhaps a second battery at 12 V would be desirable.

Comment: One always has to choose make/buy decisions in a system design.  Although >95% is possible with a forward converter using a stepdown XFMR , the complexity may detract from your time budget.  e.g. Banggood, LED driver. 
 https://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?origin=ti_panel&lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=60&VinMax=78&O1V=12&O1I=2.0&op_TA=30  ( requires login to TI and adobe security enabled by address lock icon.)

Comment: Back in the day, my radio-controlled car ran a tap off the middle of the battery compartment so that the control circuitry (5V) would be run off three AA batteries, while the motor (12V) ran off all eight.

Comment: Unfortunately, your followup question (which I turned into an edit) turns this into a shopping question, which is off-topic for this site. (However, yes, that does sound like a good choice.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's probably the only sensible approach. 24W is within the range for a flyback converter or buck converter. You could consider the [LTC3703](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3703fc.pdf), for example, though there may be better choices.

[image]

Comment: Agree, there are a ton of non-isolated synchronous buck controllers available.  Most of them come with detailed design help.  For extra efficiency, use larger FETs than what are recommended for extra low Rdson, and use an inductor with the correct inductance value but 2 or 3 times the current rating for extra low series resistance.

Comment: With such a high input voltage I'm not sure it's worth it to have a synchronous output stage (as the LTC3703 schematic above has)- an UF or Schottky diode maybe good enough and simpler.

Comment: True, but in my experience electric vehicle people are crazy for efficiency.

Comment: @AnalogKid You may be right but going for a synchronous output and placing that MOSFET instead of a UF or Schottky diode may save up to 0.5W at best conditions. I don't think that electric-vehicle-people are that hungry to save this in a 24W-load system.

Comment: That is over 2%, way over the line.  EV people go after efficiency the way aircraft designers go after weight.  How do you take 20 pounds off the weight of an airplane wing?  0.01 oz. x 32,000 fasteners.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a good DC-DC switch mode convertor is your best way to go to minimize losses in the regulator. Finding an off the shelf one that works from 72V may however be a little challenging.

Whatever you find also needs to be designed to go to sleep or otherwise disconnect itself when not required.

2A sounds a little under-rated though..